# CodeIgniter news/view doesn't work, page 404's

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am currently learning my ways with CodeIgniter and I need some help with the view news part of the tutorial. It shows a  404 page. My site is [Tristans.tk](http://tristans.tk). Click on news and then on one of the titles. Here is my code:

this is my model:

```
class News_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_news($ID=FALSE){
        if($ID===FALSE){
            $query=$this->db->order_by("post_time", "DESC")->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query=$this->db->get_where('news',array('ID'=>$ID));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

this is the news controller:

```
class News extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function view($ID){
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($ID);

        if (empty($data['news_item'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
```

and this is the view:

```
<?php
print_r($news_item);
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['content'];
?>
```

the routes:

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

news index:

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
<div class='post'>
    <h1 class='post_title'><a href="news/view/<?php echo $news_item['ID'] ?>"><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></a></h1>
    <p class='post_time'><?php echo $news_item['post_time'] ?></p>
    <p class='post_content'><?php echo $news_item['content'] ?></p>
    <span class='comment_link'><a href="news/view/<?php echo $news_item['ID'] ?>">Comment</a></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: did you have right config in `route.php` ?

Comment: Added the file. look at it.

Comment: Post your index view and method. You're using $ID instead of $slug with get_news() so the link within your index.php view should reflect that.

Comment: Either do what Charlie suggested or remove /view/ from `<a href="news/view/<?php echo $news_item['ID'] ?>">`

Comment: Yeah I did it this way, noticed it only after charlie pointed the url problem out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change this

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
```

to

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/$1';
```

by using this: `$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';`,

if you acces `yourdomain.tk/news/view/1`

that actually you access `yourdomain.tk/news/view/view/1`

Comment: Yes, this was the catch. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/show/(:any)'] = 'news/show/$1';
```

to

```
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/show/(:any)'] = 'news/show/$1';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

good luck